# How to insert object into array by id using Javascript

Tags: arrays, object, merge, lodash

I have an array and an object with different properties from the elements of the array, but they are linked together by their common identifier. The array has the following structure:

```
[{
userId: '12',
prop1: 'blue',
prop2: 'yellow'
},
{
userId: '13',
prop1: 'black',
prop2: 'white'
}]
```

My object has the following structure:

```
{id: '13',
prop3: 'heavy',
prop4: 'light'}
```

I would like to append the object to the array by their given Id, so at the end the array would look like this:

```
[{
userId: '12',
prop1: 'blue',
prop2: 'yellow'
},
{
userId: '13',
prop1: 'black',
prop2: 'white',
prop3: 'heavy',
prop4: 'light'
}]
```

As the identifier for the id is not the same, I'm having a hard time to merge them. I have tried merging via lodash using the following code, but haven't had any luck. Thank you!

```
let merged = _(myArray)
          .concat(myObject)
          .groupBy('id')
          .map(_.spread(_.merge))
          .value();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the object 'id' prop to `userId' before merging:

```js
const mergeToArr = (arr, { id: userId, ...rest }) => _(arr)
  .concat({ userId, ...rest })
  .groupBy('userId')
  .map(_.spread(_.merge))
  .value();
          
const arr = [{"userId":"12","prop1":"blue","prop2":"yellow"},{"userId":"13","prop1":"black","prop2":"white"}];1
const obj = {"id":"13","prop3":"heavy","prop4":"light"};

const result = mergeToArr(arr, obj);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pardon me for asking but why do you want to do this in that particular fashion? It seems to me rather expensive. It can also be done with a single map and merge:

```js
const arr = [{"userId":"12","prop1":"blue","prop2":"yellow"},{"userId":"13","prop1":"black","prop2":"white"}];1
const obj = {"id":"13","prop3":"heavy","prop4":"light"};

let mergeObjToArr = (o, a) => 
   _.map(a, x => _.isEqual(o.id, x.userId) ? _.merge(_.omit(o, ['id']), x) : x)

console.log(mergeObjToArr(obj, arr))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you consider this you have `map/merge/omit` vs `chain/concat/groupBy/map/spread/merge/value`.

This also can easily be converted to ES6 and skip `lodash` completely.

Unless I am miss-understanding this for which I apologize if it is the case.

Comment: thank you for your response, there was no particular reason for doing it that way, your solution is indeed more efficient. In the end, I decided to convert your solution to ES6, which gave me the fastest execution! :)